# Buck PFC controller

Tags: buck, power-factor-correction, controller

I'm considering a buck PFC for the design of my SMPS. The input will take 50 VAC rectify it using a full bridge rectifier. The buck PFC stage will then step down the voltage to a 15 V/20 A output.

I'm struggling to find a design guide for buck PFC and how to select a PWM controller. I was wondering if anyone has come across any buck PFC guide similar to the TI one here https://www.ti.com/seclit/ml/slup264/slup264.pdf (this guide uses a modified version of typical buck converter which is not what I'm trying to implement).

Also I was wondering will any current mode PWM controllers be inherently a PFC controller meaning if I find a controller that works in current mode it will also prove PFC?

Comment: Depends, how high PF do you need? If you take any buck controller, keep the input capacitor small enough and slow down the response of your buck to ~7 Hz crossover frequency and have a gigantic output capacitor to take up the slack, you will achieve decent PF. Dedicated ones will have less caveats and handle step response and CCM/DCM transition far better. Have you considered a regular boost one as frontend followed by buck?

Comment: Ideally i need a PF above 0.9. I considered the boost PFC but it wouldn't fit my application as it would then require a buck as a second stage to lower the voltage to 15 V, so i thought implementing a buck PFC will just do the trick. Problem is that its not as popular as boost converter so there aren't as many guides or reference designs. Do you know a good textbook/design guide i could follow?

Comment: You asked a similar question a few days ago I think. Maybe you deleted it? What advice was given on this deleted question or... maybe it was someone else who also linked the TI article but, it seems unlikely.

Comment: I see your point. The downside of single stage PFC is that your output capacitor grows a lot. It may end up cheaper with regular two stage. It's been 10 years since I considered a buck PFC and we ended up with BCM flyback instead. TI would be my second stop for literature after a regular web search.

Comment: I had just just finished writing you a full answer to your most recent question on the derivation of the high side voltage sensing equation, when you deleted it.  If you were to reinstate I will post the answer.